# TypeError : Image data can not be converted to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I imported a csv file using pandas in python. It had all the pixel values in a string in a single column so I split it using dataframe. But now when I am trying to plot the image from the dataset i am getting this error

```
raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")

TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd 

df_train = pd.read_csv('/root/Downloads/Deep-Learning/Projects/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('/root/Downloads/Deep-Learning/Projects/test.csv')

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df_train.head()

#every columns but the first
df_train_x = df_train.iloc[:,1:]
#only the first column
df_train_y = df_train.iloc[:,:1]

df_train_x = pd.DataFrame(df_train_x.Pixels.str.split(' ',2303).tolist())

ax = plt.subplots(1,5)
for i in range(0,5):   #validate the first 5 records
    ax[1][i].imshow(df_train_x.values[i].reshape(48,48), cmap='gray')
    ax[1][i].set_title(df_train_y.values[i])
```

What should I do?